# Vertex skinning artifacts with specific glTF models

Tags: c++, point, vertex, artifacts, skinning

I recently implemented vertex skinning in my own Vulkan engine. Pretty much all models render properly, however, I find that with Mixamo models, I get skinning artifacts. The main difference I found between "regular" glTF models and Mixamo models, is that the Mixamo models share inverse bind matrices between multiple meshes, but I highly doubt that this causes this issue.

[image: Text]

Here you can see that for some reason the vertices are pulled towards one specific point which seems to be at (0, 0, 0). I know for sure that this is **not** caused by the vertex and index loading, as the model renders properly without vertex skinning.

**Calculation of joint matrices**

```
void Object::updateJointsByNode(Node *node) {
    if (node->mesh && node->skinIndex > -1) {
        auto inverseTransform = glm::inverse(node->getLocalMatrix());
        auto skin = this->skinLookup[node->skinIndex];
        auto numberOfJoints = skin->jointsIndices.size();

        std::vector<glm::mat4> jointMatrices(numberOfJoints);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfJoints; i++) {
            jointMatrices[i] =
                    this->getNodeByIndex(skin->jointsIndices[i])->getLocalMatrix() * skin->inverseBindMatrices[i];
            jointMatrices[i] = inverseTransform * jointMatrices[i];
        }

        this->inverseBindMatrices = jointMatrices;
    }

    for (auto &child : node->children) {
        this->updateJointsByNode(child);
    }
}
```

**Calculation of vertex displacement in GLSL Vertex Shader**

```
        mat4 skinMat =
        inWeight0.x * model.jointMatrix[int(inJoint0.x)] +
        inWeight0.y * model.jointMatrix[int(inJoint0.y)] +
        inWeight0.z * model.jointMatrix[int(inJoint0.z)] +
        inWeight0.w * model.jointMatrix[int(inJoint0.w)];

        localPosition = model.model * model.local * skinMat * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
```

Comment: Are any of the matrices ill conditioned?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have tried to set both the `jointMatrix` to an identity matrix and the vertex weight to 0.25 (since they should add up to 1 and they contain 4 components). And the same problem occurs there. So if there would be ill-conditioned matrices, this problem is most likely not caused by them..

Comment: Do you have hard coded limits for the max. number of joints? If so, then that specific model may have a joint count above that limit, which may cause such artifacts.

Comment: I do, I have set it to 256, but this model only has 67 joints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the mistake I made was relatively simple. It was caused by casting the joints to the wrong type. When a glTF model uses a byte stride of size 4 for the vertex joints, the implicit type is `uint8_t` (unsigned byte) and not the `uint16_t` (unsigned short) which I was using.

[image]